# $A=\{f\in\{0,1,2\}^{\mathbb N }:f^{-1}(\{1\}) \text{ and } f^{-1}(\{2\})\text{ are finite}\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$$
A=\{f\in\{0,1,2\}^{\mathbb N }:f^{-1}(\{1\}) \text{ and } f^{-1}(\{2\})\text{ are finite}\}
$$
How can I prove that $A$ is a countable set?

Comment: For each integer $n,m \geq 0$, set $A_{n,m} = \{f:\{0,1,2\}^{\mathbb{N}} : f^{-1}(1) \subset \{1,2,\cdots,n\}, f^{-1}(2) \subset \{1,2, \cdots, m\}\}$. Argue each $A_{n,m}$ is countable.

Comment: Alternatively, show that $$|A|=\left|\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}\{0,1,2\}^n\right|\,.$$